# How to make gradle.properties machine independent

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, java-home

I'm working on 2 different machines (home vs. work) and transfer the code via GitHub, which works nice, but I just ran into a machine dependency when I added this code to the `gradle.properties` file to fix a vexing OAuth issue for google sheets:

`org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

`org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77`

Now I have to toggle between the 2 lines to get Gradle to compile. Need to check if I still need it (since I got the keystore files etc. sorted out), but I also wonder whether there is an easy solution to make this work (e.g. something like `ifdef`).

Obviously, I could just change the directory name in one of the machines I guess, but still curious how to solve this within Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with a quote from [the Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html):

> `org.gradle.java.home`
>
> Specifies the Java home for the Gradle build process. The value can be set to either a jdk or jre location, however, depending on what your build does, jdk is safer. A reasonable default is used if the setting is unspecified.

So, by default, you should not need this project property (thats what they are called in Gradle).

However, there can be reasons, that you need to specify the Java directory. For this specific project property, you can follow Ray Tayeks advice and use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable (on both systems). But there is also another approach, which can be used for any project property (and also for so-called system properties):

`gradle.properties` files can be located at different locations of the file system. Your files are located in the project directory and, therefor, they are included in your VCS. You can use them / it for project-related properties. An additional location is in the Gradle user home directory, which is by default the `.gradle` folder in your personal folder. This folder is not under version control, so simply define the property there.

Comment: yup, I didn't need them anymore (once I had the SHA-1 and debug.keystore locked in), sorry for the confusion. I did need both (at that time), the JAVA_HOME and the java.home though (as indicated in the other posts)

Answer (score 1):

try removing the line from the properties file. if that fails, try setting JAVA_HOME on each machine.

there are a lot of related [questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=gradle%20java%20home&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=gradle%20android%20java%20home%20site:stackoverflow.com).

you might try asking on the gradle [forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/).